# Iterating through a array of hashes in Ruby (parsed JSON)

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, object, each

I have this array of hashes that was created when a did a API call and ran it through JSON.parse:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "zip": "08225",
      "city": "Northfield",
      "county": "Atlantic",
      "state": "NJ",
      "distance": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "zip": "08221",
      "city": "Linwood",
      "county": "Atlantic",
      "state": "NJ",
      "distance": "1.8"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get all the zipcodes out of each object and put them into an array:

```
zipcode_array = Array.new
```

I have tried the following code:

```
locations.each do |zipcode|
    zipcode_array.push(['results'][i]['zip'])
end
```

I would like my final output to be:

```
zipcode_array = ["08225", "08221"]
```

Anyone have any tips on what I'm missing?

Comment: Tip: Instead of the verbose Java style `Array.new` you can do `[ ]` in Ruby to make a new, empty array. `Array.new` is saved for special occasions like `Array.new(10,0)` when you want an array with a particular pre-defined size and (optional) default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code seems to lack `i` variable (index) here, but actually you don't need it, since you can always use `map` function to achieve idiomatic Ruby code:

```
require "json"

response = '{
  "results": [
    {
      "zip": "08225",
      "city": "Northfield",
      "county": "Atlantic",
      "state": "NJ",
      "distance": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "zip": "08221",
      "city": "Linwood",
      "county": "Atlantic",
      "state": "NJ",
      "distance": "1.8"
    }
  ]
}'

parsed_response = JSON.parse(response)
zipcode_array = parsed_response["results"].map { |address| address["zip"] }
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of using `each` you can use `map` function to achieve this.

```
response[:results].map{|x| x[:zip]}
```

This will give you the result in array i.e

```
["08225", "08221"]
```

Comment: You are iterating the one by one

Comment: yes right. Thanks for pointing out the word `iterating`.  edited my answer for the same.

`map` will give you the new array instead of creating a new one and push into it.

Comment: This is generally the right idea, but JSON hashes will have only string keys, never symbols, at least not without conversion.